# how to find relationships in dataset with multiple variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a large project data set ,which includes numeric values like dollar amounts, and non numeric quantities like country codes, purpose codes etc
I want to find relationships between the variables. What statistical tools should I research to be able to do that ? Should I always have an hypothesis before or can I find relationships in data in general ?
I started looking into principal component analysis..but it seems that wont be very useful for non interval data.. am I right ?
Should I look into multivariate regression ? 
The problem is I don`t even know which field or topic covers such an analysis.? Any pointers  to how to begin my research would be appreciated

Comment: This might be better asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: You really need to be more specific with what you're researching... Finding "relationships" between variables is very context-dependent, so it is hard if not impossible for others to comment on it. What is it about the data that you're interested in? Also, you should expand your question and post it to [stats.stackexchange.net](http://stats.stackexchange.net).